# Method overriding passing null object

Tags: java

I am unable to understand why this program prints **String**

```
class AA {

    void m1(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object ");
    }

    void m1(String o) {
        System.out.println("String ");
    }
}

public class StringOrObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AA a = new AA();
        a.m1(null);
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand how this works to print Sting rather than Object

Comment: Because it'll try to call the most-specific method, which in this case is String.

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: I am wondering what would be the outcome if a method like "void m1(Integer o)" would be declared in addition to the two? A compile-time error?

Answer (score 3):

Dave Newton's comment is correct. The call to the method goes to the most specific possible implementation. Another example would be:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
class Biz extends Bar {}


public class Main {

    private static void meth(Foo f) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }

    private static void meth(Bar b) {
        System.out.println("Bar");
    }

    private static void meth(Biz b) {
        System.out.println("Biz");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        meth(null); // Biz will be printed
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for use of the `meth` function

Answer (score 0):

This will try and make the most specific call. Subclass object gets the preference which is String in this case.